# How to perfectly apply external images to displacement modifier without UVs warping?

Tags: displacement

I tried to project the image on the geometry, but without uvs it shows ugly edge around it. (As pictures shows)
[image]

I add the displacement modifier in all above geometries, without uvs, as you can see, the middle one is using internal noise map on it. But once I using external map, it presented ugly as the right one shows.

I'm wondering, if others also have cause not to UVs warping for certain reason? and how to amended with python or what?

Comment: This won't work like you're thinking. You will most likely need to bake it with properly configured uvs. With what you have, it looks like everything went well (or at least as well as it could go) with the uv project tool. Could you explain a bit more about why you can't use nicely unwrapped uvs?

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. I'm not aware what do you mean by "UV warping" and "internal noise map" but one way to customize displacement map is to UV uwnrap the object and [use UV map](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45843/1245) (in Displacement modifier settings choose UV); UV map should be without visible distortions obviously. One another way is to use Object mapping to make any other object control coordinates for map projection.

Comment: Thanks for your replied. The reason why I don't want to unwrap UV is because I'll generate geometries from animation:
http://makeagif.com/i/gDJejE

And unfortunately I have to choose internal renderer as my primary renderer or I have plan B for this with cycle renderer:
http://imgur.com/a/AsPXb

The other reason why I don't use object as the texture coordinates are because it shows the same problem as followed:
http://imgur.com/a/SQhjB

Comment: Well if that animation is done using curve objects you could try using curve UV mapping in Object Data > *Texture Space* > *Use UVs for mapping*. You could also try using UV Project modifier to project UVs from one object to displaced one, substitute with them those from displaced, and use them as a UV for modifier.. that made also some stretching though. Displace isn't really flexible because its texture isn't really available for edits.